# How to make Material You applications with .NET MAUI

Tags: c#, android, .net, maui, material-you

We know that it is possible to make Windows applications with .NET MAUI that inherits from the WinUI 3 styling and elements, like this one:

[image: WinUI in MAUI]

Also, I know that Android has released a new standard for developing UX, named Material You, that contains a set of elements and templates, plus the ability to access the system's color theme and reflect that in your app. A good example of a Material You based app is [Cofeegram](https://github.com/phansier/Coffeegram). You can see images of how the app looks in the README.MD file in the repo.

Now what I'm asking is the way we can make Windows-native WinUI 3 user interfaces with MAUI, can we make Material You apps too? How?

Comment: I don't think that MAUI has built-in support for Material You, but there is a library (currently in beta) that adds Material You components: https://github.com/mdc-maui/mdc-maui

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to use [Microsoft.Maui.Graphics.Controls](https://github.com/dotnet/Microsoft.Maui.Graphics.Controls) to achieve this.

`Microsoft.Maui.Graphics.Controls` is a .NET MAUI experiment that offers cross-platform, pixel-perfect, drawn controls, with three built-in themes: `Cupertino`, `Fluent` and `Material`.

For how to use this nuget, you can check: [How To Use This Library](https://github.com/dotnet/Microsoft.Maui.Graphics.Controls#how-to-use-this-library).

Comment: thanks. but this tool hasn't been updated for more than 6 months. is it stable to use?

Comment: Can you post a few more details on this? How do you use the library and set it as a nuget source? The documentation isn't very specific.

Comment: Hi @Matin, from [Microsoft.Maui.Graphics](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Maui.Graphics/), we could find that the last  updated  time is 6 days ago.   :)